# Is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[1,2^{1/n}]$ a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm a bit rusty on my ring theory and I'm working on a pet project doing some numerical work with primes in rings. I couldn't find answers to this online, so I just want to know if  $\mathbb{Z}[1,2^{1/n}]$ is a Unique Factorization Domain (so I can talk about primes sensibly). I have no idea how to go about this personally.

For my purposes it need not be true for all $n$, it would be enough that there is a closed form giving $n$ arbitrarily large for which it works, e.g. perhaps $n=2^k$? (That said, something a bit slower than an exponential would be appreciated for numerical work).

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^n-2)$ what you're looking for?

Comment: @rschwieb correct me if I'm wrong but that's exactly the same ring right?

Comment: I think it is. It's always a Noetherian domain of Krull dimension $1$, but I'm not certain if it is a UFD. I think there are some characterizations that begin that way and have more hypotheses, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: I'm not too optimistic about this being known. The reason for pessimism is that it is [unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group#Class_numbers_of_quadratic_fields) whether $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt n]$ is a UFD for infinitely many choices of $n>0$. I would think that the same question about $\Bbb{Z}[2^{1/n}]$ is more difficult, but I may, of course, be wrong. The only thing I'm sure about is that this is true for $n=2$.

Comment: For small $n$ you could try checking it "directly" by considering norms of elements. For example, for $n=3$, you can consider the possible values of $\lvert a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc\rvert$ and the corresponding elements of the form $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Answer (score 4):

Some people believe that the answer is yes. Using pari you can compute the class groups almost up to $n=40$; all of these fields seem to have class number 
$1$. For some subfamilies (i.e. $n = 2^k$) you may prove that the class number is odd. Other than that, nothing is known.

I do not think that a general proof is possible without having a complete system of independent units. I did not succeed in finding one.